# Converting my current project to fragments. Lost with my project

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am absolutely lost with my project and I need someone to point me to the right direction because right now im just looking at my code and I cant understand where to start.

MY app is all about answering questions. A player has to answer if the question is right or wrong. If he answers the right amount of questions he unlocks a new level. So until today I just thought I will need to create a new activity on every level, create questions in that activity and let it run. But just today I realized that having 100 activities of different levels is just stupid.

So I need to make my app work with fragments. The only thing i need is to make it that on each different level my app would select specific questions from the question list and display them with their values.

Right now i create questions in level activity. For example: Level1Activity

```
 //Creating questions. (Question, boolean, answer).
        final Question first = new Question("Do i understand this code?", true, "Only Jesus knows");
        final Question second = new Question("Why dont i understand this code?", false, "Im not Jesus");
        final Question third = new Question("Why I am not Jesus?", true, "2fat.");

        //Creating Lists for questions and boolean values.
        final ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        final ArrayList<Boolean> type = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        //Adding questions to the question list
        questions.add(first);
        questions.add(second);
        questions.add(third);

        // Adding boleans to the boolean list
        type.add(first.correctAnswer);
        type.add(second.correctAnswer);
        type.add(third.correctAnswer);
```

So what do i need to do so that I would not need to create a new activity with new questions on each level. Ho to make one activity and display them with fragments for all levels?

Answer (score 0):

You must start using the same fragment in all levels, and load dynamically the questions. Using one activity for each level is a really bad idea.

First, try to create a fragment, inflate it and use it, and model ONE level. Perhaps the (parent/holder) activity can control the current level, and can pass the questions to the fragment accordingly, and save attributes such the score or the game state.

Note that from the *MVC* (*Model-View-Controller*) viewpoint an Activity is a *Controller* and it is wrong to keep *Model* data in the *Controller*. The View hierarchy (the *View*) and the Activity (the *Controller*) are re-created when the screen turns. Better use a separate class, probably, a singleton, to keep the data that must survive screen turns.

Comment: So all my code with functions on how I answer questions and how I add score has to be in the fragment? Where do I need to store my questions? Should I create a new class and store all my questions there?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not need fragments either. You can have multiple layouts (used via `setContentView(int id)`), or even better, have one single layout with several instances of `TextView` on it, and set the text in these text views programmatically.

By the way, you can `startActivity()` and invoke `finish()` on the current activity (I am not saying you should do namely this, but you can).

Comment: Well yes I only have a single layout for all my levels. The only thing i need to change in each level are the questions. So your telling me I don't need fragments? What do you mean by saying several instances of TextView? Can you explain more?